# what is the meaning of にと?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> カメを助けた孫悟空、お礼**にと**そのカメが連れてきたこのじいさんはいったい?

I don't understand what purpose the と serves in this sentence.
Can someone explain, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76801/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16000/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14475/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55453/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21680/9831

Comment: Yes this answers it! I now know there is some verb omitted and that its quotative, but just to be completely sure can i ask what is actually being omitted here? if rewritten without any omissions, how would it look like?

Comment: Maybe 「『お礼に』と（言って）そのカメが連れてきたこのじいさんはいったい？」 Who is this old man, who the turtle brought (to Gokuu) saying "I brought him to show my gratitude/This is in return for saving my life"? お礼に literally means "as (=に) a return gift / token of gratitude (=お礼)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「と」 is quotative と of「彼はアメリカに行く、**と**言った」. 「に」 of 「お礼に」means 「お礼として」. 「彼はお礼**に**（=として)ハンカチをくれた」

Answer (score 3):

I think this と is being used in a quotative sense. Much like this post describes: [particle doubts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28906/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A8-particle-doubts)

So with that, I would say it's indicating the speaker's thoughts on お礼 (a thanks) and how it's perceived by them

```
お礼にとそのカメが連れてきたこのじいさんはいったい?
Who in the heck is this old man that was brought by that turtle as a thanks I guess?
```

Comment: sorry but the translation is littlebit off and i still dont understand what is quote on this. i understand the sentence, but not the exact part here. sorry.

Comment: @bulgur69 - 「お礼[に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65432/43676)」

Comment: @bulgur69 Regardless of being off or not, the と particle seems to be quotative here. Think of it as the speaker is quoting themself or letting others know of their inner thoughts. Not the traditional "They said X". As for [お礼に](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E7%A4%BC%E3%81%AB) I think treating it as a whole might be better for now. に has several functions, but as a default perspective it might be helpful to think of に as "X is going / moving towards something" in an abstract sense. お礼に here is like "X is going / moving towards (becoming in a sense) a thanks or sign of gratitude"